how to fix incompleted string dates to specific format
I have this dataframe (wih 1 million records) :
​
s_ip    <-c("ip001","ip002","ip003","ip004","ip005","ip006","ip007","ip008","ip009")
s_fide  <-c("04/10/2024 11:28","12/06/2023 22:14","02/14/2024 17:53:01","04/02/2024 21:41","02/22/2024 14:39:34","02/21/2024 21:32:39","02/29/2024 21:16:17","04/03/2024 21:19","03/21/2024 22:13:17")
df_v <- data.frame(s_ip,s_fide)
​
> df_v
   s_ip              s_fide
1 ip001    04/10/2024 11:28
2 ip002    12/06/2023 22:14
3 ip003 02/14/2024 17:53:01
4 ip004    04/02/2024 21:41
5 ip005 02/22/2024 14:39:34
6 ip006 02/21/2024 21:32:39
7 ip007 02/29/2024 21:16:17
8 ip008    04/03/2024 21:19
9 ip009 03/21/2024 22:13:17

​
And would like this other:
> df_v
   s_ip              s_fide              s_fout
1 ip001    04/10/2024 11:28 2024-04-10 11:28:00
2 ip002    12/06/2023 22:14 2023-12-06 22:14:00
3 ip003 02/14/2024 17:53:01 2024-02-14 17:53:01
4 ip004    04/02/2024 21:41 2024-04-02 21:41:00
5 ip005 02/22/2024 14:39:34 2024-02-22 14:39:34
6 ip006 02/21/2024 21:32:39 2024-02-21 21:32:39
7 ip007 02/29/2024 21:16:17 2024-02-29 21:16:17
8 ip008    04/03/2024 21:19 2024-04-03 21:19:00
9 ip009 03/21/2024 22:13:17 2024-03-21 22:13:17

​
I would like to use a function f_mybaby() to build s_fout column based on s_fide column (both columns are string or char type)
And it can be built, using the pipe %$% in this way:
​
df_v$s_fout <- df_v %$% f_mybaby(s_fide)

​
How the f_mybaby() function can be built?

Importing dates and times is common operation. The lubridate package has the function mdy_hms which should work on your data format. You can create f_mybaby as a copy of that function with f_mybaby = lubridate::mdy_hms. That will return a POSIXct class datetime object which is much more useful than a character class column. However, if you want a character string instead, try f_mybaby = function(x){ lubridate::mdy_hms(x) |> as.character() }


df_v$try1 <- df_v %$% f_mybaby(s_fide)
Warning message:
5 failed to parse.
df_v
s_ip              s_fide                try1
1 ip001    04/10/2024 11:28 2024-04-10 11:28:00
2 ip002    12/06/2023 22:14 2023-12-06 22:14:00
3 ip003 02/14/2024 17:53:01                
4 ip004    04/02/2024 21:41 2024-04-02 21:41:00
5 ip005 02/22/2024 14:39:34                
6 ip006 02/21/2024 21:32:39                
7 ip007 02/29/2024 21:16:17                
8 ip008    04/03/2024 21:19 2024-04-03 21:19:00
9 ip009 03/21/2024 22:13:17                


Some dates have NA in its results? How can fix this?

If you use mdy_hms it'll convert '04/10/2024 11:28' to '2024-04-10 00:11:28', not '2024-04-10 11:28:00'. One way to fix it is to do this:
f_mybaby <- function(x) {   lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(stringr::str_count(x, ":") == 2, lubridate::mdy_hms(x), lubridate::mdy_hm(x))) }

@DaveRosenman thank you very much, this not only solve my problem, teach to me how solve as professional in "r" (that's what I want).

Using grepl we identify missing zero seconds and paste0 them.
> f_mybaby <- \(x) {
+   zs <- !grepl(r"{\d+:\d+:\d+$}", x)
+   x[zs] <- paste0(x[zs], ':00')
+   strptime(cstr(df_v$s_fide), '%m/%d/%Y %T')
+ }
> f_mybaby(df_v$s_fide)
[1] "2024-04-10 11:28:00 CEST" "2023-12-06 22:14:00 CET" 
[3] "2024-02-14 17:53:01 CET"  "2024-04-02 21:41:00 CEST"
[5] "2024-02-22 14:39:34 CET"  "2024-02-21 21:32:39 CET" 
[7] "2024-02-29 21:16:17 CET"  "2024-04-03 21:19:00 CEST"
[9] "2024-03-21 22:13:17 CET" 
> df_v |> transform(s_fout=f_mybaby(s_fide))
   s_ip              s_fide              s_fout
1 ip001    04/10/2024 11:28 2024-04-10 11:28:00
2 ip002    12/06/2023 22:14 2023-12-06 22:14:00
3 ip003 02/14/2024 17:53:01 2024-02-14 17:53:01
4 ip004    04/02/2024 21:41 2024-04-02 21:41:00
5 ip005 02/22/2024 14:39:34 2024-02-22 14:39:34
6 ip006 02/21/2024 21:32:39 2024-02-21 21:32:39
7 ip007 02/29/2024 21:16:17 2024-02-29 21:16:17
8 ip008    04/03/2024 21:19 2024-04-03 21:19:00
9 ip009 03/21/2024 22:13:17 2024-03-21 22:13:17


Data:
> dput(df_v)
structure(list(s_ip = c("ip001", "ip002", "ip003", "ip004", "ip005", 
"ip006", "ip007", "ip008", "ip009"), s_fide = c("04/10/2024 11:28", 
"12/06/2023 22:14", "02/14/2024 17:53:01", "04/02/2024 21:41", 
"02/22/2024 14:39:34", "02/21/2024 21:32:39", "02/29/2024 21:16:17", 
"04/03/2024 21:19", "03/21/2024 22:13:17")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))


When there are hours, minutes, and seconds in your data (so there are 2 ':'s and str_count(x, ":") will give you 2), you want to use the lubridate function mdy_hms. When there are just hours and minutes (just 1 ':', so str_count(x, ";") will you give 1), you want to use mdy_hm so that 11:28 is parsed as 11:28:00 and not 00:11:28.
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
f_mybaby <- function(x) {   
     as_datetime(ifelse(str_count(x, ":") == 2, 
                        mdy_hms(x), 
                        mdy_hm(x))) 
}


With as.POSIXct and tryFormats
The function, using tidyverse because that makes keeping the date format with map_vec easier.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

to_Date <- function(dat, col, col_new) 
  dat %>% mutate({{col_new}} := map_vec(!!sym(col), ~ 
    as.POSIXct(.x, tryFormats=c("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))))

to_Date(df_v, "s_fide", "s_fout")
   s_ip              s_fide              s_fout
1 ip001    04/10/2024 11:28 2024-04-10 11:28:00
2 ip002    12/06/2023 22:14 2023-12-06 22:14:00
3 ip003 02/14/2024 17:53:01 2024-02-14 17:53:01
4 ip004    04/02/2024 21:41 2024-04-02 21:41:00
5 ip005 02/22/2024 14:39:34 2024-02-22 14:39:34
6 ip006 02/21/2024 21:32:39 2024-02-21 21:32:39
7 ip007 02/29/2024 21:16:17 2024-02-29 21:16:17
8 ip008    04/03/2024 21:19 2024-04-03 21:19:00
9 ip009 03/21/2024 22:13:17 2024-03-21 22:13:17

